# unable to bind string values which are separated with comma to a check box list

Tags: c#, asp.net

im editing languages know checkboxes in gridview i have string value english,spanish. while clicking edit button that checkboxlist items should be selected.

i want to get the gridview row column details and want to bind in one checkboxlist. i have binded all languages checkbox . i need to to make checkboxes as selected which are already in selected state.

gridview

```
     <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Languages">
                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtLanguages" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Languages") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                </EditItemTemplate>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="LblLanguages" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Languages") %>'></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
             private void bindLanguages()
                    {

                        string Languages = "English,Spanish";
                        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection())
                        {
                            conn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;
                            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
                            {
                                cmd.CommandText = "select * from tbl_Languages";
                                cmd.Connection = conn;
                                conn.Open();
                                using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                                {
                                    while (sdr.Read())
                                    {
                                        ListItem item = new ListItem();
                                        item.Text = sdr["LanguageName"].ToString();
                                        item.Value = sdr["LanguageId"].ToString();
                                        //  item.Selected = Convert.ToBoolean(sdr["IsSelected"]);
                                        chkLanguages.Items.Add(item);
                                    }
                                }
                                conn.Close();
                            }
                        }
                    }
     public void Bindemployeedetails(string str)
            {
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                string Languages = dt.Rows[0]["Languages"].ToString();//English,Hindi

 string[] words = Languages.Split(',');
            foreach (string word in words)
            {

                foreach (GridViewRow row in  ChkLanguages.Items )
                {
                    if (row.Cells[1].Text == word)
                    {
                        CheckBox chkRow = word.ToString();
                        chkRow.Checked = true;
                    }
                }
            }

            }
```

Comment: You need to add more code: what does your GridView look like? Assuming your GridView has these checkboxes for each row, how are you   defining `chkLanguages`?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try with split?

```
        string[] words = Languages.Split(',');
        foreach (string word in words)
        {
            foreach (GridViewRow row in gdvHealthProblem.Rows)
            {
                if (row.Cells[1].Text == word)
                {
                    CheckBox chkRow = row.Cells[0].FindControl("chkTableHealthProblem") as CheckBox;
                    chkRow.Checked = true;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: i dont want to edit in grid view. while clicking gridview edit button im redirecting to another page. and throug qhery string im binding all controls . i want checkboxlist control also should bind